# To let someone else follow you into your fantasy

Tags: sentence-meaning

> — You're here to corrupt one of my brightest and best.
>
> — You know what I'm offering. You have to let them decide for themselves.
>
> — Money?
>
> — Not just money. You remember. It's the chance to build cathedrals,
>   entire cities. Things that never existed, things that couldn't exist
>   in the real world.
>
> — *So you want me to let someone else follow you into your fantasy.*

I can't get the point of the last sentence. How can *let someone else follow you into your fantasy* can be bounded to the context that's appeared? What can be mean **fantasy** here?

Comment: The first speaker (Michael Caine = **Miles** in [*Inception*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)) is telling the other guy (Leonardo DiCaprio = **Cobb**) that he (Cobb) is a fantasist (his ideas are *fantasy*, not reality). Miles is obviously reluctant to agree to let his "brightest and best" (students?) get caught up in what he presumably thinks is an unrealistic way of thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "fantasy" is very literal in this context.  A "fantasy" is a dream or a dream-world; it is often contrasted with the "waking world" or "real world".  As FumbleFingers points out, Cobb is offering "the chance to build... things that couldn't exist in the real world."  In other words, Cobb is offering the chance to "build" parts of a "fantasy".